# Blazor form validation Bootstrap integration

Tags: css, validation, bootstrap-4, blazor

I have some development experience with Razor and decided to give Blazor a try.

I ran into an already familiar problem - integrating validation with Bootstrap: Blazor validation result classes do not match Bootstrap's ones.

In Razor, I can override the generated class names by adding the following code to the _ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml file:

```js
const settings = {
    valid: 'is-valid',
    invalid: 'is-invalid'
    /* other classes go here */
}
$.validator.setDefaults(settings)
$.validator.unobtrusive.options = settings
```

I tried to find solutions, but all I found was just copying of Bootstrap styles and replacing class names ([something like this](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/07/31/blazor-webassembly-form-validation-example)).

Is there some better way to do this, or will I have to duplicate all Bootstrap validation styles just to integrate it with the Blazor. I would like to avoid this, because when updating Bootstrap, I will have to do the same procedure again.

This problem seems even stranger when you remember that the default Blazor app template comes pre-configured to work with Bootstrap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do it in .NET 8 Blazor and Bootstrap v5 using [custom validation CSS class attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms/validation?view=aspnetcore-8.0#custom-validation-css-class-attributes).

Create a class that inherits from `FieldCssClassProvider` and override the *GetFieldCssClass* method:

```cs
public class BootstrapValidationFieldClassProvider : FieldCssClassProvider
{
    public override string GetFieldCssClass(EditContext editContext, in FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier)
    {
        bool isValid = editContext.IsValid(fieldIdentifier);
        bool isModified = editContext.IsModified(fieldIdentifier);

        // Blazor vs. Bootstrap:
        // isvalid = is-valid
        // isinvalid = is-invalid

        return $"{(isModified ? "modified " : "")}{(isValid ? "is-valid" : "is-invalid")}";
    }
}
```

In *OnInitialized*, call *SetFieldCssClassProvider* on your `EditContext` and pass in a new instance of the class created above:

```cs
private EditContext? editContext;

[SupplyParameterFromForm(FormName = "Form")]
private YourModel Model { get; set; } = new();

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    editContext = new(Model);
    editContext.SetFieldCssClassProvider(new BootstrapValidationFieldClassProvider());
}
```

Make your `EditForm` use the `EditContext`:

```
<EditForm EditContext="@editContext" FormName="Form">
<DataAnnotationsValidator />

@* Form contents... *@

<ValidationSummary />
</EditForm>
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the `editContext.SetFieldClassProvider(...)` only once on application startup/setup so it would be applied to all form contexts automatically?

Comment: Right now the only way I can think of is either:
1. Inherit from the `EditContext` class and override it's constructor with this call
2. Introduce some kind of `EditContextFactory` which can encapsulate this call

Comment: Either might work, but you could also wrap an `EditForm` in your own component and call SetFieldClassProvider in there. Use a render fragment for the child content and override whatever parameters you'd need (see [this example](https://blazor-university.com/templating-components-with-renderfragements/)). Then use your component instead of `EditForm` for all of your forms.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#custom-validation-class-attributes) section in the documentation.
And it worked for `is-valid` and `is-invalid` classes.

And I also found [that](https://chrissainty.com/creating-a-custom-validation-message-component-for-blazor-forms/) wonderful article about how to implement custom `ValidationMessage` in 25-30 lines of code.